# Provider org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found while migrating the code from Java 1.4 to Java 1.6

Tags: java, apache

I'm trying to migrate my application from Java **1.4** to Java **1.6** but encountered with the following error when running on Java 1.6. Note that the error doesnt oocur while running the code on Java 1.4 / Java 1.5

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError:
    Provider org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea why is it giving me this error? It seems to be referring to `crimson.jar` which is obviously not present but why is it referring to this jar ?

Comment: Can you please the java code along with full error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a java migration, take some time  to go through the [announced compatibility issues](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html).

Your issue is probably documented in above link, relevant notes copied below.

> Apache - The org.apache classes, which have never been supported J2SE
> APIs but are used by the javax.xml package, have moved in 5.0 to
> com.sun.org.apache. package.internal so that they won't clash with
> more recent, developer-downloaded versions of the classes. Any
> applications that depend on the org.apache classes being part of the
> J2SE release must do one of the following to work in 5.0:
>
> Code the application so it uses only the supported interfaces that are
> part of JAXP. Download the org.apache.xalan classes from Apache.
>
> For more information, see bug [4740355](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4740355).